# angular-cli: How to resolve file extensions?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm moving from webpack to angular-cli and I need it to resolve minified js files. In webpack you'd add `extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', 'min.js', '.json']` to webpack.config. What is the equivalent in angular-cli?

Comment: Your question is directed at a solution... what are you trying to do? Is there a particular library you're trying to include?

Comment: I'm trying to include Wijmo 5. The documentation is based on systemjs and the webpack solution on the forums http://wijmo.com/topic/wijmo-5-and-webpack/ involves copying amd files to `node_modules/wijmo`. The amd files are the *min.js files in question. I found a solution of renaming the *.min.js files to *.js to get angular-cli's webpack to resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Angular CLI only supports loading `.js` and `.ts` files, as shown [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-common.ts#L36).

You might have luck adding the path of the file to the `scripts` property of the `angular-cli.json` file (added in recent version before beta-16, not sure which one).

Apart from that, extending Webpack config is planned, but has no ETA, as the team hasn't worked on a suitable design for it yet.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't try the `scripts` property but I found a solution of renaming the *.min.js files to *.js to get angular-cli's webpack to resolve them with minimal change to my projects structure.